# I cannot see the .SVN folders anymore?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I recently upgraded my tortoise to version 1.7. It's been a while now I cannot see the .svn folders. I used to copy folders to replicate some code, enter the folder and delete the .svn of the copied version so that it considers the code as new. I cannot do this anymore :(

Anyone knows what is going on?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Subversion 1.7 switched to a single-folder structure, like many DVCSes (git, bazaar, etc.) - the only .svn folder is in the root folder now, and this contains all of the info for the checkout.

You should now be able to simply copy the folder and check it in.

Comment: it appears that the format of 'entries' file was changed (almost disappeared). I've some automation scripts who used to get revision info from that file. How do I do it no (in a portable way, in a very sand-box environment where I cannot run 'svn info').

Comment: @Uri: You should post that as a new question. I suspect it might also depend on what you're trying to do with that information.

Comment: I THINK I WILL GO OUT AND GET DRUNK BECAUSE OF THIS! Thanks SVN, finally (party)!

Answer (score 5):

They have been moved from being inside each subfolder of your working copy, and now are all in one place.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Anders said, the new version of SVN 1.7 gets rid of individual `.svn` folders within each directory. Now, the head node contains `./svn` along with a subdirectory named `pristine` that contains the original svn copy of all those files/directories. This makes it a lot nicer to copy from `project1` to `project2` without having to run special scripts to remove all those remnant `.svn` folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can try exporting. It usually removes all .svn files and you can create a fresh project everytime with the exported code..!