# _svn folder in one working director but not another

Tags: svn, google-chrome-extension, tortoisesvn

I am using Tortoise Subversion to source control some Chrome Extensions I am working on. When I build the extension in the Chrome settings area on one machine, it complains about the hidden `_svn` folder and won't compile. I therefore need to temporarily remove it and put it back later, before checking in my changes.

On another machine this doesn't happen and the working copy here doesn't appear to have an `_svn` folder in that directory? How can this be? Doesn't every folder require an `_svn` directory for source control to work? I've looked at the view options in the folder and even if I show hidden system files and folders it doesn't appear to be there? The only difference between the two machines is one (without the `_svn` folder) is running a newer version of the Tortoise SVN Client.

**UPDATE ----**

I now realise that the inconsistency was due to using two different versions of the Tortoise SVN client. It seems 1.7+ switched to using a single _svn folder situated in the root of the repository (See post below). I have now upgraded and can compile the extension without the _svn folder mucking things up :)

[I cannot see the .SVN folders anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137483/i-cannot-see-the-svn-folders-anymore)

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I used Subversion, but isn't the directory usually named .svn? I've never seen _svn before. Try that and see whether things are any different.

By the way, you'll be sad someday if your build script encounters an error and doesn't make it to the part where the svn directories are put back where they belong, and you lose your uncommitted svn history. Rather than removing specific source-control directories, instead consider copying the stuff you *want* to a temporary directory. Like this:

```
TMPDIR=/tmp/myextension
CWD=`pwd`
mkdir $TMPDIR
pushd $TMPDIR
cp $CWD/*.js .
cp $CWD/*.html .
cp $CWD/*.css .
pushd $TMPDIR
zip -r /tmp/myextension.zip .
popd
rm -rf $TMPDIR
popd
```

(That's imaginary Bash code, and you seem to be on Windows, but you get the idea.) What's nice about this approach is that you can do build-time processing of your source files as you copy them to the temp directory, such as inserting a new version number into the manifest through sed.

Comment: Thanks for your input @sowbug, the folder is definitely appearing as _svn although perhaps it was once .svn in a prev release. I solved my problem, please see appended notes.

Comment: Cool. Tried to phrase the answer in a way that related to the google-chrome-extension tag, but it turned out it had nothing to do with it.

Comment: @sowbug they use too outdated Visual Studio http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#vs-asp-net